# ExtJs TabPanel e gridview

Tags: extjs-4

Acredito ser uma questão bem simples mais ja tentei de tudo e não resolveu.

Uma gridview na tabpanel não esta exibindo a pagingtollbar, como tem muita linha na grid passa a area de visão. O Scroll da tabpanel não funciona, e não consigo acesso ao botões de navegação.

Sem definir na mão a altura do grid como fazer para ser ajustada ao tamanho da tela automaticamente? Sem scroll da tabpanel somente scroll da gridview.

Obrigado

Codigo da grid

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.view.GridView', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

requires: ['Ext.toolbar.Paging'],

alias: 'widget.gridV',
//title: 'Importação',

store: 'GridStore',
selType: 'checkboxmodel',

selModel: {
    checkOnly: true,
    injectCheckbox: 1
},

layout: {
    type: 'border',
    align: 'center'
},

loadMask: true,
autoScroll: true,
stateful: true,
multiSelect: true,

//height: 620,
//autoHeight: true,

viewConfig: {
    stripeRows: true,
    enableTextSelection: true,
    forceFit: true,

    //autoFill: true,
    //scrollOffset: 0
},

columns: [
    {   header: 'Id',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        sortable: false,
        width: 50,
        fixed: true
    },{
        header: "Url",
        dataIndex: 'url',
        sortable: true
    }

],
initComponent: function() {
    this.dockedItems = [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Importar',
                    action: 'selimp',
                    tooltip: 'Importar TXT'
                },{
                    text: 'Excluir',
                    action: 'delete',
                    tooltip: 'Deletar Registros'
                },{
                    text: 'Excluir Todos',
                    action: 'deleteAll',
                    tooltip: 'Deletar todos os Registros'
                },{
                    text: 'Transferir Dados',
                    action: 'transfDados',
                    tooltip: 'Transferencia de registros'
                }
            ]
        },{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            store: 'GridStore',
            displayInfo: true,
            emptyMsg: "Nenhum registro encontrado."
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Codigo Layout/Container/TabPanel

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

requires:[
    'ImpPdf.view.GridView',
    'Ext.tab.Panel'
],
xtype: 'app-main',

layout: {
    type: 'border',
    align: 'left'
},

defaults: {
    bodyBorder: false,
    //collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    bodyPadding: 0
},

items: [
{
    xtype: 'container',
    region: 'north',
    split: false,
    height: 40,
    html: '<h2>Primeiro aplicativo</h2>',
    style:{
        marginBottom: '10px',
        marginLeft: '5px',
        color: 'white'
    }
},{
    title: 'Navegação',
    region: 'west',
    floatable: false,
    margins: '5 0 0 0',
    width: 180,
    minWidth: 100,
    maxWidth: 250
},{
    //title: 'Main',
    region: 'center',
    collapsible: false,
    margins: '5 0 0 0',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        activeTab: 0,

        items:[{
            title: 'Importação',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'gridV'
            }]
        },{
            title: 'Transferencia'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Definição de altura automaticamente é algo um pouco complicado.
O mais simples é utilizar o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Agora pro scroll funcionar, tu vai ter que definir o a propriedade autoScroll como true no teu tabpanel

> autoScroll: true

depois que o scroll funcionar o conteúdo deve se ajustar sozinho.